# Timeline Development for Android

Tags: java, android, xml

i want to create a timeline that looks like this (is there any library can it help   [image]

who can gives me an idea on how to do or a tutorial please

thank you

Comment: It seems nothing more than a ListView... Just use "clever" graphic elements to give the **illusion** of a connecting line.

Comment: Install the app, then use **`uiautomatorviewer`** to see how they do it.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
It's a simple ListView or RecyclerView with cells like those : 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/date"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="#C00"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/date"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:background="#C00"
            android:padding="10dp"
            tools:text="22"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>

        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/date"
            android:background="#C00"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:textColor="#C00"
            tools:text="This saturday"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```